# Множественная замена в Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text

Вопрос к знатокам. Ситуация: дано ряд чисел (упростим: единиц), по одной в каждой строке. Выделить их в Sublime Text 2 - не вопрос. Но вот как превратить в последовательность 1, 2, 3, ... ?

Пример ситуации: вы продумываете структуру будущей БД, готовите данные для заливки и нужно обновить ключи (ключей может быть несколько сотен):

```
INSERT INTO titles (id, name) VALUES
(1, 'Петушок, петушок...'),
(1, 'Наши уточки с утра...'),
(1, 'Водичка, водичка...'),
(1, 'Ладушки, ладушки!..'),
(1, 'Дождик, дождик, пуще...');
```

чтобы получилось:

```
INSERT INTO titles (id, name) VALUES
(1, 'Петушок, петушок...'),
(2, 'Наши уточки с утра...'),
(3, 'Водичка, водичка...'),
(4, 'Ладушки, ладушки!..'),
(5, 'Дождик, дождик, пуще...');
```

*UPD. Нашелся плагин [Incrementor](https://github.com/eBookArchitects/Incrementor), который может генерировать последовательность чисел, используя поиск и замену. Подобную задачу решает.*

**Усложним.** Как в Sublime Text 2 быстро сделать подобные замены:

```
1,2,3, ..., 7 → Sun, Mon, Tue...
1,2,3, ..., 12 → Jan, Feb, Mar...
```

Comment: видимо нужно писать планиг. Особенно для усложненного варианта.

Comment: Всем отвечающим: обратите внимание на UPD, если не смотрите на дату вопроса.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не знаю как из ряда единиц сделать последовательность 1, 2, 3.

Знаю, что можно используя плагин Emmet(ex Zen Coding) написать {$, }*15 и нажать Tab и получить 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
Понятное дело, что можно указать не 15, а любое количество цифр.

Для усложнённого варианта, придётся писать плагин ( сам не нашёл нигде похожий ), причём нужно же будет учитывать к какому году относятся даты и к какому месяцу.

Comment: Суть не в генерации ряда (хотя ссылка на Emmet крайне полезна), а в поиске и замене с инкрементом. Внёс уточнения в запрос.

Comment: Ну по первому варианту вопроса было не совсем понятно, что Вы это имеете ввиду, но хорошо, что Вы сами нашли ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы быстро в разные позиции кода вставить последовательность чисел и несколько других типов последовательностей, можно использовать плагин **Text Pastry** (https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Text%20Pastry)

Выделяете мультиселектом нужные места, нажимаете ctrl+alt+n (на Windows) - и вписываете параметр, указывающий какая последовательность вам нужна. Например, набрав "i" - получите последовательность "1, 2, 3.. n". Есть параметр и для дней недели.

Answer (score 1):

Лучший плагин, что я нашел - это [InsertNums](https://github.com/jbrooksuk/InsertNums)

Он позволяет задать начальное значение последовательности первым параметром и вторым параметром - шаг.

Т.е. параметры `10 5` для пяти строк с выделенными `1` заменят `1` соответственно на `10 15 20 25 30`.

В вашем варианте достаточно указать только первый параметр, равный `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Кстати конкретно к вашему примеру можно все единицы заменить просто на `NULL`, если поле `id` в таблице является автоинкрементным